# How to name each instance of a nested dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I wrote this code to create a nested dictionary, but I am unable to name each instance.

```
def genvlandict(num,attrs):
    val=num
    vlans = []
    for i in range(val):
       vlans.append(dict([("Vlan_Attr"+str(i)+'.'+str(x), "val"+str(i)+'.'+str(x)) for x in range(0, attrs, +1)]))
    return vlans

print(json.dumps(genvlandict(5,3), indent=1))
```

Can I get some help to get a name for each dictionary instance within the nested dictionary?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The dicts are inside a list. Why do they need names?

Answer (score 0):

Change `vlans` to a dictionary? With some minimal changes, your code would be something like:

```
import json

def genvlandict(num,attrs):
    val=num
    vlans = {}
    for i in range(val):
       vlans['dict%d' % i] = dict([("Vlan_Attr"+str(i)+'.'+str(x), "val"+str(i)+'.'+str(x)) for x in range(0, attrs, +1)])
    return vlans

print(json.dumps(genvlandict(5,3), indent=1))
```

Resulting in:

```
>>> 
{
 "dict4": {
  "Vlan_Attr4.2": "val4.2", 
  "Vlan_Attr4.1": "val4.1", 
  "Vlan_Attr4.0": "val4.0"
 }, 
 "dict1": {
  "Vlan_Attr1.2": "val1.2", 
  "Vlan_Attr1.0": "val1.0", 
  "Vlan_Attr1.1": "val1.1"
 }, 
 "dict0": {
  "Vlan_Attr0.2": "val0.2", 
  "Vlan_Attr0.1": "val0.1", 
  "Vlan_Attr0.0": "val0.0"
 }, 
 "dict3": {
  "Vlan_Attr3.0": "val3.0", 
  "Vlan_Attr3.1": "val3.1", 
  "Vlan_Attr3.2": "val3.2"
 }, 
 "dict2": {
  "Vlan_Attr2.1": "val2.1", 
  "Vlan_Attr2.0": "val2.0", 
  "Vlan_Attr2.2": "val2.2"
 }
}
>>>
```